# Regex filter XAML tags with specific attribute

Tags: regex, xaml

I have the following Regex that matches XAML tags:

<[^<>]*>

This would return both of these lines:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" />
<Button x:Name="Button2" Content="foo" />
```

What I want to do is filter out tags that have "Content="foo"" in them.

There are similar examples out there, but in this case the quotation marks are tripping me up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use an XML parser.  **Please**.

Comment: See the classic stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: The above is a simplified example of my real problem. I can't use an XML parser in the context of said real problem, have to use Regex.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use an XML parser? Please post your real problem, not "simplified examples" whose solutions won't work for your "real problem".

Comment: You should always **tag** what language you are using your Regex from. I think it's C# considering you are using XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<([^<>](?!\sContent\s*=\s*("foo"|'foo')))*>
```

This... But PLEASE, don't use Regexes to parse XML.

Each character we capture with `[^<>]` we check if it is followed by one space and the `Content="foo"`. If true we fail so the capture is rollbacked of one character and the Regex checks for the terminating `>`.

http://regexr.com?2umr9

You have to click around a little so that the Regex is "activated".

Some small notes: this Regex is WRONG because it's trying to parse XML, but ignoring this, it won't be fooled by `SContent="foo"` (ignored) or `Content='foo'` (catched) or `:Content='foo'` (ignored) or `Content =  "foo"` (catched). This clearly if you are using a Regex parser that treats `\s` as the same list of space characters as XML :-) Otherwise some "strange, alien" spaces could break it a little. Remember to use it with case sensitive parsing!

Comment: This is a somewhat odd way of going about it, but it should produce the correct results. +1 from me. I'd suggest replacing the `\s+` with `\b`, however.

Comment: @Justin No, unless you want to catch `:Content`. My first iteration used it, but then I changed idea (I have rewrote at least three times this Regex)

Comment: I know, but I wouldn't worry about that, personally. Worrying about `:Content` is likely overkill. Also, in your current pattern, you can replace the `[^<>]*\s+` in the lookbehind with just `\s` and it will mean the same.

Comment: @Justin Strange... I was sure my Regex was different. Probably I copy-pasted from the wrong RegExr. Flash hates me and doesn't let me copy paste half the time. I'm for the Overkill! "if you have to do something, might as well do it right"

Comment: You still don't need the `+`. In the position you have it, `\s+` will do the same thing as `\s`.

Comment: @Justin And it will be probably faster now! :-) :-) With less lookahead! Thanks! In the end, doing a good Regex is an iterative process. You begin small and you grow it... And then you try to reduce it again :-) :-)

Answer (score 2):

### Regex

```
/<[^>]*Content="foo".*?>/g
```

Which means start regex (`/`) and search for `<` folled by zero or more *not* `>`s (`[^>]*`) followed by `Content="foo"` followed by zero or more anythings (`.*`) *un*-greedily, followed by '>' and end regex `/`.

### Test Code:

Written in javascipt, but can be ported into other languages easily.

```
x = ['<Button x:Name="Button1" /><Button x:Name="Button2" Content="foo" /><Button x:Name="Button1" /><Button Content="foo" />']

console.log( x[0].match(/<[^>]*Content="foo".*?>/g) )
```

---

## Updated to match exact opposite (as required by OP)

### Regex

Using negative lookahead assertion, as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word/406408#406408)

```
<((?!Content="foo")[^>])*>
```

Which means match `<` followed by zero or more not `>`s (`[^>]*`) that each do not have `Content="foo"` in front of them followed by `>`. Brackets added for necessary grouping.

But remember - using regex as a substitute for XML parsing will make people on stack overflow get really angry with you... so better to post questions like this anonymously. ;)

Comment: This is very close! It actually returns the opposite of what I want, I'm looking to filter OUT the Content="foo" attribute. FYI, since I know Regex performs differently in different contexts, I'm using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test. Thanks for the help so far, especially the thoughtful description of the regex elements.